# Return array of first matches by field value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

For example I have collection with following type:

```
[
    { batch: false, type: '' },
    { batch: false, type: '' },
    { batch: true, type: '123' },
    { batch: true, type: '123' },
    { batch: true, type: '123' },
    { batch: true, type: '234' },
    { batch: true, type: '234' },
    { batch: true, type: '234' },
    { batch: true, type: '234' },
    { batch: true, type: '567' },
    { batch: true, type: '567' }
]
```

so question is, how to return array of objects which have `{batch: false}` and if `{batch: true}` return only first object with same `{type}` field, basically I want get following response:

```
[
    { batch: false, type: '' },
    { batch: false, type: '' },
    { batch: true, type: '123' },
    { batch: true, type: '234' },
    { batch: true, type: '567' }
]
```

Comment: I edited out the `_id` field in the documents because I think it's redundant here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following aggregation pipeline

```
db.getCollection('yourCollection').aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                k1: {
                    $cond: {
                        if: "$batch",
                        then: null,
                        else: "$_id"
                    }
                },
                k2: "$type"
            },
            batch: { $first: "$batch" },
            type: { $first: "$type" }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            batch: 1,
            type: 1
        }
    }
])
```

which results in

```
/* 1 */
{
    "batch" : false,
    "type" : ""
}

/* 2 */
{
    "batch" : false,
    "type" : ""
}

/* 3 */
{
    "batch" : true,
    "type" : "123"
}

/* 4 */
{
    "batch" : true,
    "type" : "567"
}

/* 5 */
{
    "batch" : true,
    "type" : "234"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Run the following aggregation pipeline in which you would need to have a condition in your `$group` key which satisfies the given criteria:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": { "$cond": [ "$batch", "$type", "$_id" ] },
            "batch": { "$first": "$batch" },
            "type": { "$first": "$type" }
        }
    },
    { "$project": {  "_id": 0, "batch": 1, "type": 1  } }
])
```

Comment: Nice answer but with the (in theory) possible risk of collision when both `type` and `_id` come from the same domain